# Should i use cygwin for nutch and solr integration?

Tags: solr, cygwin, nutch

Hi I am creating a search engine for a website using nutch and solr but i am unable to execute bin/nutch(command) in my command prompt. can i execute it in command prompt or should i use cygwin?

I am using solr 3.6.2 and nutch 1.7, pls provide me solution as soon as possibe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cygwin, heres an excellent guide to set them up together:

http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html